# Actor Critic model returns NaN for action probabilities

Tags: reinforcement-learning

I am new to RL and walking through the Keras implementation of Actor Critic.

As a variant of it, I am trying to learn the strategy for WORDLE. However, after a few runs, my action spaces all go down to nan.

actions = [nan nan nan ... nan nan nan]

Not sure what's happening. Could someone have any insights or pointers?

Attaching my code for reference.

Thanks

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import random
import string
import random
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers

# Configuration parameters for the whole setup
gamma = 0.9  # Discount factor for past rewards
max_runs = 10000
eps = np.finfo(np.float32).eps.item()  # Smallest number such that 1.0 + eps != 1.0

my_file = open("<wordle set of words data path>", "r")
content = my_file.read()
content = list(content.split('\n'))

lower_alphabet = list(string.ascii_letters)[:26]

def get_secret_word():
    return random.choice(content)

def reset_available_action_space():
    return [1 for i in range(len(content))]

def reset_guessed_alphabet_state():
    return [0 for i in range(len(lower_alphabet))]

# array of 26 which represents which alphabet is available in word
def reset_contains_alphabet_state():
    return [0 for i in range(len(lower_alphabet))]

# Array of 26*5. 
# First 26 represent which alphabet was correctly guessed at the first slot
# Second 26 represent which alphabet was correctly guessed at the second slot. And so on for the next 5 slots.
def reset_correct_alphabet_pos_state():
    return [0 for i in range(len(lower_alphabet)*5)]

def select_and_update_AVAILABLE_ACTION_SPACE(actions):
    action_index = 0
    while AVAILABLE_ACTION_SPACE[actions[action_index]] == False:
        action_index += 1
    AVAILABLE_ACTION_SPACE[actions[action_index]] = 0
    return actions[action_index]

def env_reset():
    AVAILABLE_ACTION_SPACE = reset_available_action_space()
    guessed_alphabet_state = reset_guessed_alphabet_state()
    contains_alphabet_state = reset_contains_alphabet_state()
    correct_alphabet_pos_state = reset_correct_alphabet_pos_state()
    state = guessed_alphabet_state + contains_alphabet_state + correct_alphabet_pos_state
    SECRET_WORD = get_secret_word()
    return state, SECRET_WORD, AVAILABLE_ACTION_SPACE

def env_step(action, state):
    guessed_word = content[action]
    
    guessed_alphabet_state = state[:26]
    contains_alphabet_state = state[26:52]
    correct_alphabet_pos_state = state[52:]
    
    done = False
    reward = -10
    
    if SECRET_WORD == guessed_word:
        done = True
        reward = 10
    secret_word = list(SECRET_WORD)
    guessed_word = list(guessed_word)
    for index_, char_ in enumerate(guessed_word):
        alphabet_index = lower_alphabet.index(char_)
        guessed_alphabet_state[alphabet_index] = 1
        if char_ in secret_word:
            contains_alphabet_state[alphabet_index] = 1
            if secret_word[index_] == char_:
                correct_alphabet_pos_state[26*index_ + alphabet_index] = 1
    state = guessed_alphabet_state + contains_alphabet_state + correct_alphabet_pos_state
    return state, reward, done

num_inputs = 182
num_actions = len(content)
num_hidden_1 = 256
num_hidden_2 = 128

inputs = layers.Input(shape=(num_inputs,))
common = layers.Dense(num_hidden_1, activation="relu")(inputs)
common = layers.Dense(num_hidden_2, activation="relu")(common)
action = layers.Dense(num_actions, activation="softmax")(common)
critic = layers.Dense(1)(common)

model = keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=[action, critic])

optimizer = keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001)
huber_loss = keras.losses.Huber()
action_probs_history = []
critic_value_history = []
rewards_history = []
running_reward = 0
episode_count = 0

for runs in range(max_runs):
    max_steps_per_episode = 6
    state, SECRET_WORD, AVAILABLE_ACTION_SPACE = env_reset()
    episode_reward = 0
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        for timestep in range(max_steps_per_episode):
            state_tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(state)
            state_tensor = tf.expand_dims(state, 0)
            
            action_probs, critic_value = model(state_tensor)
            critic_value_history.append(critic_value[0, 0])

            actions = np.random.choice(num_actions, size=max_steps_per_episode+1, replace = False, p=np.squeeze(action_probs))
            action = select_and_update_AVAILABLE_ACTION_SPACE(actions)

            action_probs_history.append(tf.math.log(action_probs[0, action]))

            state, reward, done = env_step(action, state)
            rewards_history.append(reward)
            episode_reward += reward

            if done:
                break
                
        # Update running reward to check condition for solving
        running_reward = 0.05 * episode_reward + (1 - 0.05) * running_reward

        # Calculate expected value from rewards
        # - At each timestep what was the total reward received after that timestep
        # - Rewards in the past are discounted by multiplying them with gamma
        # - These are the labels for our critic
        returns = []
        discounted_sum = 0
        for r in rewards_history[::-1]:
            discounted_sum = r + gamma * discounted_sum
            returns.insert(0, discounted_sum)

        # Normalize
        returns = np.array(returns)
        returns = (returns - np.mean(returns)) / (np.std(returns) + eps)
        returns = returns.tolist()

        # Calculating loss values to update our network
        history = zip(action_probs_history, critic_value_history, returns)
        actor_losses = []
        critic_losses = []
        for log_prob, value, ret in history:
            # At this point in history, the critic estimated that we would get a
            # total reward = `value` in the future. We took an action with log probability
            # of `log_prob` and ended up recieving a total reward = `ret`.
            # The actor must be updated so that it predicts an action that leads to
            # high rewards (compared to critic's estimate) with high probability.
            diff = ret - value
            actor_losses.append(-log_prob * diff)  # actor loss

            # The critic must be updated so that it predicts a better estimate of
            # the future rewards.
            critic_losses.append(
                huber_loss(tf.expand_dims(value, 0), tf.expand_dims(ret, 0))
            )

        # Backpropagation
        loss_value = sum(actor_losses) + sum(critic_losses)
        grads = tape.gradient(loss_value, model.trainable_variables)
        optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, model.trainable_variables))

        # Clear the loss and reward history
        action_probs_history.clear()
        critic_value_history.clear()
        rewards_history.clear()  
        
    # Log details
    episode_count += 1
    if episode_count % 10 == 0:
        template = "running reward: {:.2f} at episode {}"
        print(template.format(running_reward, episode_count))
wordle set of words data path => https://gist.github.com/cfreshman/a03ef2cba789d8cf00c08f767e0fad7b
```

My State Space is [guessed alphabets, alphabets contained in the secret word, alphabet in the correct position]

guessed alphabets => Array of 26 size (a-z)

alphabets contained in the secret word => Array of 26 size (a-z)

alphabet in the correct position => Array of 26 * 5 [(a-z), (a-z), (a-z), (a-z), (a-z)] (as each word is 5 letters)

The Available action spaces get updated after every action. The previously taken actions are no longer available for future actions.

I have tried both relu and tanh for activation

Observation: Critic Value keeps increasing to an extremely large values